# Heroku Sails Application accessing mongodb located on mongohq

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, sails.js

Our application(node js using sails framework) is trying to access mongodb which is located on MongoHQ. When application is run from local system it is working fine. But once application is installed then values are not saving mongodb on mongohq rather its is saving somewhere in heruko. Configuration in adapter,js is as follows

adapters: {
 'default': 'mongo',
 mongo: {
 module: 'sails-mongo',
 url: process.env.DB_URL,
 schema: 'true'
 }
 }

and DB_URL = mongodb://AdsPlaces:(redacted)@kahana.mongohq.com:10091/AdsPlaces.

Package content

dependencies: {
    "sails": "0.9.8",
    "sails-disk": "~0.9.0",
    "sails-mongo": "*",
    "skipper": "^0.1.8"
  }

When ever form is getting saved then values are getting saved somewhere on heroku default location but not on mongodb://AdsPlaces:(redacted)@kahana.mongohq.com:10091/AdsPlaces. Because of this our data is getting deleted each time updated application is installed on heroku.
 Please help

Answer (score 1):

Check if the heroku instance current environment is production or development. By default, sails js will check for `NODE_ENV` to determine current environment. I believe that your application on heroku is running on development hence the models are using `'sails-disk'` adapter.

You may try to check your `config/env/production.js` and with heroku toolbelt, run `heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production`.